# How can I adjust the path to my destination folder?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, frontend, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm trying to configure the 'dest' property of uglify (grunt), but I'm having a problem.

This is my code:

```
    uglify:{
        js: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: ['js-dev/*.js','js-dev/**/*.js'],
                dest: 'js',
            }]
        }
    }
```

The problem is when I run my grunt, the final destination folder is   `js/js-dev/[All my files]`. But I just want `js/[All my files]`, without the `js-dev`.

Does anyone know how I can adjust this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You just need to set the `cwd` to `js-dev` and drop `js-dev` from your `src` declarations. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify#compiling-all-files-in-a-folder-dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `cwd` to `js-dev` and drop it from your `src` declarations.

```
uglify:{
    js: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'js-dev',
            src: ['*.js','**/*.js'],
            dest: '../js',
        }]
    }
}
```